# How to sort the "do" output?

Tags: sorting

So I have function (FindCoefficients) that iterates through some values to find the maximum value for a function. It is much quicker to hold the non-linear values constant and do a find maximum for the linear coeffiecients then to do a non linear optimization for a complicated function.

This is the main line that I'm struggling with:

```
Do[Print[a , b, FindCoefficients[a, b]], {a, 1, 10, 1}, {b, 1, 10, 1}]
```

This gives me the output of

11{value of maximum, other info}

12{value of maximum, other info}

13{value of maximum, other info}

...

21{value of maximum, other info}

...

1010{value of maximum, other info}

Is there any way to sort my output from greatest to smallest, so I can easily pick out the maximum?

Comment: Use `Table`, not `Do`. Then you can `Sort`. You might find parts of this a useful reading: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12

Answer (score 2):

```
SortBy[ Table[{a , b, FindCoefficients[a, b]} , {a, 1, 10, 1}, {b, 1, 10, 1}],{3}]
```

sorts your Table according to the third column.